# SQL-query for grouping continuous numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Lets say i have the following table:

```
| ... | orderId | serialNumber | type          | ... |
|-----|---------|--------------|---------------|-----|
| ... | 1       | 01           | someType      | ... |
| ... | 1       | 02           | someType      | ... |
| ... | 1       | 03           | someOtherType | ... |
| ... | 1       | 04           | someOtherType | ... |
| ... | 1       | 05           | someType      | ... |
| ... | 1       | 06           | someType      | ... |
| ... | 2       | 07           | someType      | ... |
| ... | 2       | 08           | someType      | ... |
```

I want my query to generate the following result:

```
| orderId | count | min | max | type          |
|---------|-------|-----|-----|---------------|
| 1       | 2     |  01 | 02  | someType      |
| 1       | 2     |  03 | 04  | someOtherType |
| 1       | 2     |  05 | 06  | someType      |
| 2       | 4     |  07 | 08  | someType      |
```

I want groups by type and orderId. When the serialNumber is not ongoing, a new entry should be created.

This is my current query:

```
SELECT
 orderId,
 count(*) AS count,
 min(serialNumber) AS min,
 max(serialNumber) AS max,
 type
FROM tblMyTable
group by type, orderId
order by orderId
```

but the result it creates is wrong:

```
| orderId | count | min | max | type          |
|---------|-------|-----|-----|---------------|
| 1       | 4     |  01 | 06  | someType      |  <-- this should be 2 entries
| 1       | 2     |  03 | 04  | someOtherType |
| 2       | 2     |  07 | 08  | someType      |
```

As you can see it does not detect that serialNumber 03 and 04 belongs to another description. This leads to an incorrect count and max-value.

I don't know how to add a criteria that checks for a continuous serialNumber.

EDIT:
There can also occur single records like:

```
 | orderId | count | min | max | type          |
 |---------|-------|-----|-----|---------------|
 | 1337    | 1     |  10 | 10  | someNewType   |
```

Comment: I guess you interpret the SQL grouping in a bit wrong way. The grouping is don't take records order into account. It's aggregating all records with the same values of grouping fields (orderId and type in your case). To split the one line into two like you want you should find some field which makes this rows different.

Comment: What is your rdbms? Sql Server, postgres, oracle?

Comment: MS Transact-Sql

Comment: all types came in pairs?

Comment: no, there can also appear single types. i have updated my question with this information.

Comment: @daly do you have any other column in the table that identify a pair uniquely ?

Comment: @MJoy unfortunately not :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem, but I would use the difference of row numbers approach:

```
select orderid, count(*), min(serialNumber), max(serialNumber), type
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by orderid order by serialnumber) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by orderid, type order by serialnumber) as seqnum_type
      from t
     ) t
group by orderid, type, (seqnum - seqnum_type)
order by orderid, min(serialNumber);
```

Your `serialnumber` looks like a string, but it has numeric values.  If you can trust the sequencing of it, you don't even need both row number values:

```
select orderid, count(*), min(serialNumber), max(serialNumber), type
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by orderid, type order by serialnumber) as seqnum_type
      from t
     ) t
group by orderid, type, (serialnumber - seqnum_type)
order by orderid, min(serialNumber);
```

The reason this works is a little hard to explain, but quite obvious if you run the subqueries.  You will see how the difference between the row numbers identifies the groups that you want to identify.

Comment: Much cleaner ... I just got the Flag approach stuck in my little head  +1

Answer (score 3):

Here is yet another option assuming `[serialNumber]` dictates the sequence.

This is commonly called a **Gaps-and-Islands** problem

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
    Select *
          ,Grp = sum(Flg) over (order by [serialNumber])
        From (
              Select *
                    ,Flg = case when concat(orderid,type)<> lag(concat(orderid,type),1) over (Order by [serialNumber]) then 1 else 0 end
               From  YourTable
             ) A
)
Select [orderid]
      ,[count] = count(*)
      ,[min]   = min ([serialNumber])
      ,[max]   = max ([serialNumber])
      ,[type]  = max([type])
 From  cte
 Group by [orderid],Grp
```

**Returns**

```
orderid count   min max type
1       2       01  02  someType
1       2       03  04  someOtherType
1       2       05  06  someType
2       2       07  08  someType
```

Answer (score 0):

This may need some running but is a start.

**[SQL DEMO](https://rextester.com/ZDGP43271)**

```
with cte as (
      SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by type, orderId order by serialNumber) as rn
      FROM Table1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte c1
LEFT JOIN cte c2
  ON c1.orderId =  c2.orderId
 AND c1.type = c2.type
 AND c1.rn = c2.rn-1
 AND c1.rn % 2  = 1
```

**OUTPUT**

```
+----+---------+--------------+---------------+----+---------+--------------+---------------+------+
|    | orderId | serialNumber |     type      | rn | orderId | serialNumber |     type      |  rn  |
+----+---------+--------------+---------------+----+---------+--------------+---------------+------+
|  1 |       1 |            3 | someOtherType |  1 | 1       | 4            | someOtherType | 2    |
|  2 |       1 |            4 | someOtherType |  2 | NULL    | NULL         | NULL          | NULL |
|  3 |       1 |            1 | someType      |  1 | 1       | 2            | someType      | 2    |
|  4 |       1 |            2 | someType      |  2 | NULL    | NULL         | NULL          | NULL |
|  5 |       1 |            5 | someType      |  3 | 1       | 6            | someType      | 4    |
|  6 |       1 |            6 | someType      |  4 | NULL    | NULL         | NULL          | NULL |
|  7 |       2 |            7 | someType      |  1 | 2       | 8            | someType      | 2    |
|  8 |       2 |            8 | someType      |  2 | NULL    | NULL         | NULL          | NULL |
+----+---------+--------------+---------------+----+---------+--------------+---------------+------+
```